# haskell sieve prime number

Tags: haskell, sieve

In the following prime sieve:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve [2..]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

What do `x | x <- xs` and `` x `mod` p > 0 `` mean?

Comment: Please search for List Comprehensions. Also, mod is the Modulo function.

Comment: the list-comprehension syntax is where to close to the set-syntax you would use in math - so it means *the list of all `x` in `xs` where ``x `mod` p > 0``*

Comment: I recommend reading through all of http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/haskell/ for a quick overview of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`` [ x | x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0] `` is a list of `x`s made of elements from `xs`, but only those elements that satisfy the `` x `mod` p > 0 `` condition (`mod` returns the [remainder after the first number is divided by the second number](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~en1000/haskell/inbuilt.html#div), so you're asking for elements of `xs` that aren't divisible by `p`).